# Badges in achievement drop-down switches based on site

Tags: bug, badges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The achievements dialog drop-down in the top bar shows the recent achievements across all sites. Each entry has a site-specific icon next to it, so you know where it's from. Badges, however, seem to be displayed relative to the site that you're on.

Here is the view from [TeX.SE](//tex.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Here is the view from [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Here is the view from [GIS](//gis.stackexchange.com):

[image]

This seems like a bug; the badge icon should also stay with the site.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I considered that one but it's an FR while this and the other are bugs.  Either way it's a duplicate, so Werner, you'll find answers there.  (status-by-design)

Comment: same thing, different tags?

Comment: Thanks all. Clear duplicate.